# Get Instagram posts count for profile

Tags: php, api, instagram, posts

I'm using PHP to build an application that gets some statistics from individual Instagram accounts.
I do a get request to the following URL to get a JSON formatted string:

[https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1](https://www.instagram.com/%7Busername%7D/?__a=1)

With json_decode, I get the followers and the followings by:

```
$follows = $data['user']['follows']['count'];
$followedBy = $data['user']['followed_by']['count'];
```

But I don't know how to get the posts count.

For example for NASA profile:
https://www.instagram.com/nasa/

... I need the number (currently) 1.967.

Any idea?

And a final question: do I have to use API Key to get the stats, or the GET to the above URL is enough?

Comment: looks like the api refers to `posts` as `media` https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is wrong with

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->user->media->count;
```

it just spit out the correct post count as you wanted?

Comment: wow thanks, that's the answer. For some reason I was reading incorrectly the json return (I was sure I had made also a search to text for "1967" with no results! Anyway :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As of now (2020) Instagram has made some changes to the JSON response and the code below does the same as the accepted answer above, also with formatted output.

```
$ig = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1'));
echo number_format($ig->graphql->user->edge_owner_to_timeline_media->count);
```